# jaxb annotations for verbose OTA XML

Tags: jaxb

For my sins, I'm working with [Airline OTA XML](http://www.opentravel.org/2011A/OTA_AirFlifoRS.xsd). It has verbose elements such as:

```
<FlightInfo>
    <Success />
    <DepartureAirport LocationCode="LHR" />
    <ArrivalAirport LocationCode="LAX" />
</FlightInfo>
```

where the presence of a Success element means the response is successful, and airport codes are embedded as Attributes in holding Elements.

To preserve my sanity as I write java code, I want to convert this into a simple POJO like this:

```
public class FlightInfo {
   private boolean success;
   private String departureAirport;
   private String arrivalAirport;
}
```

Using JAXB, what is the recommended approach for this - use XmlJavaTypeAdapter for all these elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

You could use the `@XmlPath` extension in MOXy for the `departureAirport` and `arrivalAirport` fields:

```
   @XmlPath("DepartureAirport/@LocationCode")
   private String departureAirport;

   @XmlPath("ArrivalAirport/@LocationCode")
   private String arrivalAirport;
```

And you could use an `XmlAdapter` to represent the `boolean` field `success` with the presence or absence of the `Success` element:

```
   @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(SuccessAdapter.class)
   private boolean success;
```

**FlightInfo**

Below is what your `FlightInfo` class would look like with MOXy and JAXB annotations:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="FlightInfo")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class FlightInfo {

   @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(SuccessAdapter.class)
   private boolean success;

   @XmlPath("DepartureAirport/@LocationCode")
   private String departureAirport;

   @XmlPath("ArrivalAirport/@LocationCode")
   private String arrivalAirport;

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/represent-string-values-as-element.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html